# DateTime format string pattern

Tags: c#, vb.net, datetime, date, formatting

Could someone please guide me on the correct format string to display a time in the following format?

```
   Original: #7/28/2011 09:00:03 AM#
   Required Format: 9am

   //BUT if the minutes part contains a value I want it to look like this

   Original: #7/28/2011 09:21:03 AM#
   Required Format: 9:21am
```

Is there one format string I can use to accomplish this?

PS: I have tried `h:mmtt` but as expected that doesnt quite give me what I want

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Format strings won't help.  You want to conditionally format the string based on a value.  You will have to check the minutes value yourself and apply the appropriate format string based on whether there are 0 minutes or not.

```
DateTime dateValue = DateTime.Parse("7/28/2011 09:00:03 AM");
string formattedString;
if (dateValue.Minute == 0)
    formattedString = dateValue.ToString(@"M/d/yyyy Htt");
else
    formattedString = dateValue.ToString(@"M/d/yyyy H:mmtt");
```

Comment: Make this an extension method and it'll be golden ;)

Comment: @Kelly The string value has to be explicitly converted to a DateTime.

Comment: @Keith: I was referring to the extra parse statement in you had in your if statement. I see you have removed that parse now.

Comment: Thanks Kelly. My first example was a little off before I corrected it but I missed your comment at the time. Thanks for pointing it out though.

Answer (score 1):

you need to write logic to stip out the 00 condition where whenever you found 00 as minutes then return only hour value else return hour and minutes values like

```
dtobj.Minute.Equals(00) ? dtobj.ToString("dd/MM/yy hhtt") : dtobj.ToString("dd/MM/yy hh:mmtt")
```

Answer (score 1):

try~

```
string str = "7/28/2011 09:21:03 AM";
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(str, "M/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine(dt.Minute == 0 ? dt.ToString("HHtt"):dt.ToString("HH:mmtt"));
```